# How to altered facebook permissions using my application?

Tags: android, facebook, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

i am making on application in marshmallow 6.0 but when i am trying to share  a uri using Intent,i am not able to share image on facebook when the facebook permissions for storage is off through my app.

how to make facebook storage permissions to ON or how to prompt dialog for permissions to be granted while sharing link using our app.

Answer (score 1):

> Dangerous permissions cover areas where the app wants data or resources that involve the user's private information, or could potentially affect the user's stored data or the operation of other apps. For example, the ability to read the user's contacts is a dangerous permission. If an app declares that it needs a dangerous permission, the user has to explicitly grant the permission to the app.

Check this tutorial, easy mode by google:
https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions

for more information:
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous